# String Contains and String Does Not Contain in Same Command

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this. There are thousands of variations of the `symptom` column.

```
ID Symptoms
1  neck infection, fever
2  tonsil wound
3  lymph laceration
4  tonsil sore 
5  Leg break 
5  ear ache, headache
```

I want all IDs who HAD either "neck", "lymph" or "tonsil" as a symptom, and of these IDs, I only want flag a 1 for a new variable `Lymph_Node_Neck`, for those who DID NOT have the following adjoining text "abscess","laceration" or "peritonsillar".

So for example, if I were to run the correct code for this request:

```
ID Symptoms                      Lymph_Node_Neck
1  neck infection, fever               1
2  tonsil peritonsillar                0
3  lymph laceration                    0
4  tonsil sore, cough                  1 
5  Leg break                           0
6  ear ache, headache                  0
```

Here is the code I'm attempting to use to accomplish this analysis but when I run it I get an error.

```
LABS_TAT.loc[:,"Lymph_Node_Neck"]=np.where((LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("neck|lymph|tonsil", case=False)&(~LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("abscess|laceration|peritonsillar", case=False)),1,0)

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Am I getting this error because I'm trying to combine a string contains with a string does not contain?

Comment: Instead of a onliner better would be to define two mask as ``mask_1 = cond_1`` & ``mask_2 = cond_2`` then use the mask variable as ``np.where(mask_1 & ~mask_2, 1, 0)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

This is a syntax error, meaning it's not even attempting to execute your code yet. EOF means End Of File. So it's reached the end of the file, but it was expecting to see some other syntax. In this case a closing parenthesis:

```
LABS_TAT.loc[:,"Lymph_Node_Neck"]=np.where((LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("neck|lymph|tonsil", case=False)&(~LABS_TAT["Symptoms"].str.contains("abscess|laceration|peritonsillar", case=False)),1,0))
```